# Pulumi / Terraform / Cloudformation : enable SSH access to Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, aws-cloudformation, pulumi

Using the `eb` CLI, one can enable SSH through `eb ssh`. This recreates all instances, and I'm assuming it updates the security group ingress rules & adds the correct keys to the instances.
How can one programmatically achieve this (terraform, pulumi, CF ... - I am using Pulumi but any will do) ?

Answer (score 0):

In CloudFormation, for example, in your [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticbeanstalk-configurationtemplate.html) you can use [OptionSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticbeanstalk-configurationtemplate.html#cfn-elasticbeanstalk-configurationtemplate-optionsettings) to provide `EC2KeyName`.

For instance;

```
Resources:

  MyConfingTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties: 
      ApplicationName: YourApplicationName
      OptionSettings: 
      
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value: <key-pair-name>         

      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running Python 3.7
```

You don't have to modify security groups. They will automatically allow ssh.